# Why can't I run my method from inside hamsters.js?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I want to run this function, for update my db in multithread mode:

```
var params = {'array': array};

hamsters.run(params, function () {

    var arr = params.array;

    arr.forEach(function (query) {


        comanda.sincro.query(query, function () {

            //Optional
            rtn.data.push(query);

        });

        console.log(query);

    });

}, function (output) {

    //console.log("MT TEST 2", output, "CB TRUE");

    console.log("MT TEST", output);

    if (typeof (cB) === "function") {
        cB(true);
    }

}, hamsters.maxThreads, true);
```

But I get this error:

```
hamsters.js:886 Error Hamster #0: Line 9 in undefined: Uncaught ReferenceError: comanda is not definedonerror @ hamsters.js:886
hamsters.js:886 Error Hamster #1: Line 9 in undefined: Uncaught ReferenceError: comanda is not definedonerror @ hamsters.js:886
hamsters.js:886 Error Hamster #2: Line 9 in undefined: Uncaught ReferenceError: comanda is not definedonerror @ hamsters.js:886
hamsters.js:886 Error Hamster #3: Line 9 in undefined: Uncaught ReferenceError: comanda is not defined
```

Why, if my function is defined and is working in my function's callbacks?

Otherwise, what is the sense of using Hamsters.js, if I can't do a simple operation on my element?

Comment: What/where/how are `comanda` and `rtn` defined?

Comment: "rtn" I think it is defined in the object hamster, and "comanda" is defined by me, outside from the object

Comment: The error is clearly stating that comanda is not known, so you  think you defined it but somewhere outside of this code you made a mistake

Comment: ok, but how can I fix?

Comment: I also tried to use the normal query, but the function "openDatabase" is always not defined...

Comment: We can't know how to fix this because the code that is the root cause of the problem is not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

creator of Hamsters.js. The issue i see is that you're mixing the scope of your main thread and your multithreaded logic. Remember that web workers (threads) are sandboxed environments, anything you want to be possible inside a thread needs to be passed into the thread.

comanda.sincro.query doesn't exist because you didn't pass it with the params object and so forth.